# Remove block merging

Tags: html, css

I have two blocks that should normally be laid out like this

The problem is that if we reduce the height of the screen, then these blocks will merge like this

Here are the blocks and styles themselves

```
<div id="navShareLink" class="rectangle" style="display: none">
    Here are just pictures with links
</div>

<div id="scrollTopButtonBlog" class="top-button-article" style="display: none">
    There is also a text and a picture
</div>
```

In fact, you need to do something with the `rectangle` and `top-button-article` classes

Here are their styles

```
.rectangle {
  z-index: 998;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  padding: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 27%;
  height: 216px;
  width: 48px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 24px;
  right: 12px;
}

.top-button-article {
  z-index: 999;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 54%;
}
```

Alternatively, they have a `top` percentage value, and because of this the whole problem, but how to make them stand exactly in the center and do not merge?

Comment: Positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try this:

basicly I put both divs in a parent div called `sidebar`. Now the `sidebar` is in controll of the placement and layout of both child divs. I used a flexbox to align both items. By adding margins and stuff to the childs you can play around with the positioning.

```
<div id="sidebar">

  <div id="navShareLink" class="rectangle" style="display: none">
    Here are just pictures with links
  </div>

  <div id="scrollTopButtonBlog" class="top-button-article" style="display: none">
    There is also a text and a picture
  </div>

</div>
```

and here the css:

```
#sidebar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
            
.rectangle {
  z-index: 998;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  height: 216px;
  width: 48px;
  border-radius: 24px;
}

.top-button-article {
  z-index: 999;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div id="navShareLink" class="rectangle">
  <a href="#">FB</a>
  <a href="#">TW</a>
  <a href="#">LI</a>
  <a href="#">OT</a>
  <a href="#">ME</a>
</div>

<div id="scrollTopButtonBlog" class="top-button-article">
  <span>To Top</span>
</div>

<style>
.rectangle {
  z-index: 998;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  padding: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  height: 216px;
  width: 48px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 24px;
  right: 12px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.rectangle a{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: #c1c1c1;
    color: #000;
}
.top-button-article {
  z-index: 999;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 48px;
  height: 80px;
  top: 270px;
  right: 12px;
  border-radius: 24px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.top-button-article span {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  display: block;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 14px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by explaining what changes you made and why.

Comment: and on top of that by using an actual snippet